# create a loop to the random function

Tags: javascript, loops

I want to create a loop so that the numbers change continuously until the end of the loop, and then when I click the button I want the value to be saved in the variable tot, but I press the button
. thank you

```
generateOptions function () {
  randomValues ​​var = [];
  var currentValue ;
  
  while ( randomValues.length <10 ) {
    currentValue = Math.floor ( Math.random () * 11) + 1;
    
   
    if ( randomValues.indexOf ( currentValue ) < 0) {
      randomValues.push ( currentValue ) ;
    }
  }

  
 

  { return
    option : randomValues ​​,
  
  } ;
}

$ (function () {
  var setup = generateOptions ();
  var tot = 0 ; // variable saved total value
  $ ("# button1" ) . val ( setup.opzione [ 0]);
  $ ("# button2 "). val ( setup.opzione [1] ) ;
  $ ("# button3 "). val ( setup.opzione [2] ) ;
  $ ("# Button4 .") val ( setup.opzione [4] ) ;
  $ ("# Button5 .") val ( setup.opzione [5]) ;
  $ ("# button6 .") val ( setup.opzione [6] ) ;
  $ ("# button7 .") val ( setup.opzione [7] ) ;
  $ ("# button8 .") val ( setup.opzione [8]) ;
  $ ("# button9 .") val ( setup.opzione [9]) ;
  $ (" input.finish .") on ( "click" , function () {
    var SelectedValue = parseInt ($ (this). val ( ) , 10);
     
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to understand from your question exactly what you're trying to accomplish. However from the code it looks like you're trying to return an array of random values from a function, output each of these values to different buttons, then store the value of whatever button is clicked. If this is the case other than the syntax errors your code looks like it will work as long as each of your buttons has the `finish` class. If you would like the value to be stored in the `tot` variable like your question suggests simply swap out `var selectedValue` for `tot`.

You have alot of syntax errors there. I suggest you open the console by pressing f12 and going to the console tab to debug the code, this would be a more helpful exercise than someone just telling you where they are. I suggest you break the code up to do this, try using `console.log(generateOptions())` to view what the function returns as well as commenting out different points within the function to see where the problem lies. Once you got the function working try testing with one button to start off then go from there. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: this is not an answer.